# In a distributed program, how to recovey its corresponding data when a process crashes

Tags: architecture, distributed-system, data-consistency, crash-recovery

I have a distributed program, for example, it has ten process, and all of them will execute some job, all job info will storage to a same MySQL database. At a same moment, there was a lot of running job in database, and they are belong to different process. When one process crash, how can I recovery it running job info in a new process.
By the way, my enviroment has MySQL and zookeeper.

Comment: That depends on the nature of the jobs. Edit the question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an ID to every running  process
You should set an ID to every running job
You should put code process in try...catch...finally , to know which ID trashed
You should manage relations between process ID and its IDs jobs